# How to get reports from web services in efficient manner

Tags: database, web-services

We have a distributed system with 3 sites. Each site has its own services that encapsulates both logic and data.All services are using mysql database as the persistence system and SOAP services. But we get a trouble with database reports since maintaining services encapsulation prevents from accessing database directly. So How to get reports from web services without breaking encapsulation provided by web services and in the same time maintaining efficiency.

Comment: Which is actually a "report" for you ? and which are exactly the troubles you're facing ? You may also want to indicate the web technology you're using and the underlying persistence system.

Comment: sorry for missing these details.

Comment: additionally share with us the exact technology / framework you're using for you web-services and business-logic.

Comment: we are using WSO2 Web Services Framework for PHP

Answer (score 0):

Share a common data-structure known by the services and the clients.

I'd implement a very **simple serializable data-structure**, and have these entities to be interchanged, known between the client and the server(s). And of course all services would output the same data-structures.

If you have already a persistence layer (if not, build one), with DAO/DAL(s) entities, have them to be responsible of querying the data and performing the transformation between the original data to these new common data-structures. A helper class would do that automatically.

What I think it could be this data-structure, is an entity based on a set of rows and columns (array of object instances), plus, an array of columns identifiers, known by both the client and the server, so that your model knows which are the columns being requested by the client.

In this way you could have a client requesting 3 columns of the report, and a different client, might be requesting many others of the same report.

Additionally, I'd of course, not including any HTML in the data, just the raw data, and your clients to be responsible on how to present that data.

This above is a little bit abstract.. but hope it helps you anyway.